# Material design size of input

Tags: angular, input, material-design

I want to material-design in my angular2 project and so far it works.
But the size of input (ie11, edge, chrome, firefox) is very large, size of text too. How can I change that ? I didn't do anything except steps how to install material-design.

[Example of normal input size & angular input size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdVGC.png)

And here is example how it should look like: https://material.angular.io/components/component/input

login.component.html:

```
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="worker.password" placeholder="Password" />

<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="worker.login" placeholder="Login" />
</md-input-container>
```

login.component.ts

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdInputModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { MdButtonModule, MdInputModule, MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
// .. ngmodule
imports: [..., MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdInputModule],
```

My styles.css and login.component.css files are empty.

Index.html :

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/login">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The MD Library should be up to spec right out of the box. Are you sure your zoom settings in the browser are fine? Try CTRL+0

Comment: Also try inspecting it in the computed style tab. Font size should be 16px. Note that the MD library uses `em` and `font-size: 100%` in a few places, so global css file settings may mess it up.

Comment: Also, if using angular-CLI, try adding the import into `styles.css` like so: `@import ~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css`. Could be a pathing issue.